# Adjust QTableView Height to its content (few lines)

Tags: qt, qtableview, vcpkg

Below a screenshot of my application. I want to get rid of the white spaces after the last tables lines marked by red rectangles :

[image]

The horizontal size policy is expanding and the vertical one is minimum and for other tables it is both set to expanding.

I'm using this method I found in another SO question but as you can see the result is not flawless.

```
    void verticalResizeTableViewToContents(QTableView* tableView)
    {
        tableView->resizeRowsToContents();

        // does it work ?
        tableView->setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents);

        int rowTotalHeight = 0;

        // Rows height
        int count = tableView->verticalHeader()->count();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            // 2018-03 edit: only account for row if it is visible
            if (!tableView->verticalHeader()->isSectionHidden(i)) {
                rowTotalHeight += tableView->verticalHeader()->sectionSize(i);
            }
        }

        // Check for scrollbar visibility
        if (!tableView->horizontalScrollBar()->isHidden())
        {
            rowTotalHeight += tableView->horizontalScrollBar()->height();
        }

        // Check for header visibility
        if (!tableView->horizontalHeader()->isHidden())
        {
            rowTotalHeight += tableView->horizontalHeader()->height();
        }
        tableView->setMaximumHeight(rowTotalHeight);
    }
```

Somewhere, I'm using this code to setup one of the tables :

```
m_Internals->Ui.Measures->setModel(mm->getPh66MeasuresModel());
    m_Internals->Ui.Measures->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsMovable(true);
    m_Internals->Ui.Measures->horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections(false);
    m_Internals->Ui.Measures->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Interactive);
    m_Internals->Ui.Measures->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

m_Internals->Ui.Measures->verticalHeader()->hide();
    m_Internals->Ui.Measures->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    verticalResizeTableViewToContents(m_Internals->Ui.Measures);
```

I'm using Qt ModelView pattern to populate/update the tables.

Update : I made a small example to reproduce this issue with QTableView : https://github.com/embeddedmz/QTableViewAdjustPolicyNotWorkingProperly

Using the latest Qt version (from Qt official installer), there's no issue. However, using the Qt library provided by vcpkg (outdated for sure) the issue is there.

With Qt provided by vcpkg :
[image]

With the latest Qt provided by the Qt Company (update not the latest, it's 5.12.11) :
[image]

Comment: `setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents)` and `setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum)` for views with `QSpacerItem(0,0,Expanding,Expanding)` in the bottom of window do the job. It's all because `resizeRowsToContents()` I guess. And do resize rows AFTER set policy.

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it. means that now I don't know which stylesheet did you set and how  fill your table , provide a simple program and explain there or put your code in Github and attach its link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Qt 5.12.11, the bug does not exist. So I took a look at the QAbstractScrollArea::sizeHint code of this version and compared it with the implementation used in recent versions of Qt and found that setting verticalScrollBarPolicy to "ScrollBarAlwaysOff" the "AdjustToContents" adjustment policy works. The default value was "ScrollBarAsNeeded", in fact we can see that this value is not handled but since in Qt 5.12.11 we only compare the vertical|horizontal]scrollBarPolicy to Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn it prevents this bug from appearing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something fully buildable on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, post a link to the complete project (strip it down to just this part) and I will take an actual stab at it.

My gut, having worked with Qt for years, is telling me you are being burned by Margins.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contentsMargins

You probably need to set a bottom margin of Zero.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmargins.html#setBottom

If you retrieve the margins for those widgets you will probably find they are non-zero.

Comment: Margins are external to the whole table (the widget) so I tried it and it doesn't work ! there's still a white space after the last line.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setContentsMargins

Sets the margins around the contents of the widget to have the sizes left, top, right, and bottom. The margins are used by the layout system, and may be used by subclasses to specify the area to draw in (e.g. excluding the frame).

Changing the margins will trigger a resizeEvent().

Comment: OK, I set margins to zeroes and also called setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContentsOnFirstShow); also changed size policies but I still have an extra space in the table. I will try to make a simple Qt project to reproduce the issue. Haters already gave me 2 downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, without buildable code shooting something like this is very difficult. You did scan the Qt bug database to see if this isn't another one of Qt's more than decade old bugs, right?

Comment: Yes it's a Qt bug, it doesn't exist with the latest version. I'm using Qt through vcpkg library manager and I checked it's upgraded in that tool. I will use the Qt6 version provided by vcpkg.

Answer (score 0):

you can also fix your problem with one trick, this problem happens for you because your data is lower than the table size. I clone your project and **change sizepolicy**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I will try your solution very soon. and if it does work, I will give you the bounty as I'm having issues with vcpkg Qt6.

Comment: Qt 6 is not stable yet , I use Qt 5.15.2

Comment: I tested the code I published on github on Windows 8.1 + vcpkg and I don't have the issue that I got with Win10 + vcpkg. I will test your trick monday when I will be back to the office.

Comment: It's a workaround, but it is still a Qt bug related to setSizeAdjustPolicy and as I have already mentionned in my previous comment, I don't have this issue with my personal computer running Win 8.1 + vcpkg.